# ui-boostrap : carousel not sliding anymore after migrating from 0.12.0 to 0.13.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I work on an Angular module in which ui-boostrap is used to create a carousel. 
ui-boostrap 0.12.0 was used from here, and everything worked fine : on start, it used to slide automatically from one element to the next, with an animated transition. Just like it does in this page : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.0/#/carousel

I just upgraded ui-boostrap to version 0.13.4, and now the next element is just *replacing* the former, there isn't a transition anymore. 
But I can't see any difference on this version documentation that could explain this change of behaviour : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/carousel. I see no new dependency, no new attribute related to the transition...

Unfortunatelly, the code is too embedded in our module and I can't easily post it for you. I will try and reproduce the behaviour on a plunker if I have time. But I don't have it right now.

If I just reverse the version of ui-bootstrap back to 0.12.0, without any other change, it works again. The version of AngularJS is 1.4.8.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out ui-bootstrap 0.13.4 requires `ngAnimate`, where version 0.12.0 does not.

I loaded the angular-animate script and added ngAnimate as a dependency to the module, and it works now.

See : [Angular Bootstrap Carousel Slide Transition not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021084/angular-bootstrap-carousel-slide-transition-not-working-correctly)